# C# grab text from first item in listview in Details view

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I have a listview (in Details view) that is filled dynamically. I want to grab the text from the the first item in the listview.
This code doesn't work

```
lstSalesppl.Items[0].Selected = true;
string teamLeader = lstSalesppl.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

I get an error on the second line: Invalid argument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index' however the same code works in another method when the listview item is double clicked

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to duplicate your error, but it works fine for me. I've setup a lstSalesppl and added some entries, then put the code you listed in an onClick() event of a button and it worked fine. Can you post more code so I can see it in context? Thanks.

Comment: Do you handle `ItemSelectionChanged` even? if yes - please provide that code for us

Comment: Thanks for the replies- Hunter's worked (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
lstSalesppl.Items[0].Text
```

rather than

```
lstSalesppl.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

`lstSalesppl.SelectedItems` may not be bound to the `Selected` attribute

---

[ListView.SelectedItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)

> The SelectedItems property **will not contain any items if the property is accessed before the ListView handle is created**, which typically occurs when ListView is initially loaded for display in the form. You can check to see if the handle is created with the **IsHandleCreated** property. When the MultiSelect property is set to true, this property returns a collection containing the items that are selected in the ListView. For a single-selection ListView, this property returns a collection containing the only selected item in the ListView. For more information on the tasks that can be performed with the items in the collection, see ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection.